# ¿Como elimino la barra blanca al seleccionar texto en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Tengo una molesta al programar en Android Studio, cuando quiero seleccionar múltiples líneas de código siempre al final se la selección se pone la barra blanca y, si deseo eliminar el código seleccionado usando la tecla Backspace, la selección se mueve un espacio hacia la izquierda, también no me deja copiar texto ya que al hacer el Ctrl + c, el texto seleccionado de deselecciona teniendo que darle clic derecho y dar en la opción “copy”.

La barra blanca la desactivo presionado la tecla Insert, pero esto solo es temporal, ya que el hecho de volver a seleccionar código vuelve a generar la misma barra blanca.

Agradecería alguna solución sobre como desactivar ese comportamiento en el IDE, gracias.

[image: Ejemplo de como queda el código seleccionado]